# When can you get an UITableView content size in the life cycle of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, contentsize

I have a `UITableView` where new rows should appear at the bottom. When the table is empty the way I do it is by creating a header for the `UITableView` that takes up the whole frame of it and when new rows are added eat away the header.

This all works fine, but when I exit the `viewController` and then reopen it the `UITableView` should be recreated as well as the header. If there are some rows in the `UITableView` I need to calculate the header's size according to the `content size` of the `UITableView`. The problem is that in `ViewWillAppear` content size is not set yet and in `ViewDidAppear` it's too late since the `UITableView` is already rendered on screen and adding a header at that point makes the rows "jump" down. I want to avoid that behaviour.

So my question is at what point can I get the `content size` of an `UITableView` before it is rendered on screen.

Comment: Can you post some code? I checked one of my table view controllers and the content size was already set in `viewWillAppear`. Blind guess: your data source isn't set up until after `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Took a closer look at my code and I'm calling `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`. So you might want to try that.

Comment: That was it.     reloadData did the trick. Thank you!